# Criar objeto e enviar por ajax - Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Olá,

Podem me ajudar a criar um objeto com este código e enviar por ajax.

```js
console.log("cadastro-assessoria trabalhando");
//Variáveis

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.target // activated tab
        var target_tab = e.target.href.split('#')[1];
  set_tabindex(target_tab);
  console.log(target_tab);
 }); 
 obter_assessoria_ajax();
 /*** Eventos ***/
    $('#btn_salvar').click(function () {
     salvar_assessoria();
    });

});

function obter_assessoria_ajax() {
    var ret;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
  dataType: "JSON",
     url : "assessoria/obter_assessoria",
        success: (function (tbl_assessoria) {
            _obj_assessoria = tbl_assessoria;
   console.log(tbl_assessoria);
            obj_form();
            ret = true;
        }),
        error: (function (erro) {
            //TrataErroAjax(erro);
            ret = false;
        })
    });
    return ret;
}

function obj_form()
{
 $('#txt_id').val(_obj_assessoria.id);
 $('#txt_cnpj').val(_obj_assessoria.cnpj);
 $('#txt_inscricao_estadual').val(_obj_assessoria.inscricao_estadual);
  $('#txt_razao_social').val(_obj_assessoria.razao_social);
  $('#txt_nome_fantasia').val(_obj_assessoria.nome_fantasia);
 $('#txt_logradouro').val(_obj_assessoria.logradouro);
 $('#txt_numero').val(_obj_assessoria.numero);
 $('#txt_complemento').val(_obj_assessoria.complemento);
 $('#txt_bairro').val(_obj_assessoria.bairro);
 $('#txt_cidade').val(_obj_assessoria.cidade);
 $('#txt_cep').val(_obj_assessoria.cep);
 $('#txt_uf').val(_obj_assessoria.uf);
 $('#txt_observacao').val(_obj_assessoria.observacao);
 $('#txt_nome').val(_obj_assessoria.nome);
 $('#txt_telefone').val(_obj_assessoria.telefone);
 $('#txt_celular').val(_obj_assessoria.celular);
 $('#txt_email').val(_obj_assessoria.email);
 $('#txt_qtde_licenca').val(_obj_assessoria.qtde_licenca);
 //Formato Data pt-br  
    var dt_expiracao = _obj_assessoria.dt_expiracao.split('-').reverse().join("/");    
 $('#txt_dt_expiracao').val(dt_expiracao);
 $('#txt_chave').val(_obj_assessoria.chave);
 set_mascara();
}

function salvar_assessoria() {
 $('#btn_salvar').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Salvando');
 $('#btn_salvar').attr('disabled', true);
 remove_mascara();
    var ret;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'JSON',
  url : "assessoria/salvar_assessoria",
  data: $('#form').serialize(),
  success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $('#btn_salvar').html('<i class="fa fa-save"></i> Salvar');
            $('#btn_salvar').attr('disabled', false);
      toastr.success('Cadastro atualizado com sucesso');
      ret = true;     
       },  
        error: function (erro) {      
            //TrataErroAjax(erro);
   toastr.danger('Erro ao salvar');
   alert(erro);
            ret = false;
  }
 });
 event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

/*** Operações da tela ***/
//Função para adicionar index aos tabs
function set_tabindex(tab) {
    var lb_desbloquear = '';
    if (tab == "tab_licenca_uso") {
        _index_tab = 2;
        lb_desbloquear = 'Desbloquear';
 } else {
        _index_tab = 1;
 }
 
    $('#btn_desbloquear_item span').text(lb_desbloquear);
 
    if (_index_tab > 1)
 $('#btn_desbloquear_item').show();
    else
 $('#btn_desbloquear_item').hide();
}

$("#btn_desbloquear_item").click(function() {
  //$("#qtde_licenca").attr('disabled', !$("#qtde_licenca").attr('disabled'));
  //$("#dt_expiracao").attr('disabled', !$("#dt_expiracao").attr('disabled'));
  //$("#chave").attr('disabled', !$("#chave").attr('disabled'));  
});
```

Sei que na hora de enviar eu enviaria assim:
`data: { 'objeto': JSON.stringify(objeto_criado) },`

A minha intenção é enviar como objeto para poder tratar os campos que contem mascaras, por exemplo CNPJ, CEP, TELEFONE, etc...

Da forma atual, está enviando sem eu ter possibilidade de remover as mascaras do campo.
Ou se existe possibilidade eu desconheço.

Comment: Nao sei se e a melhor forma e também não testei, mais e se voce faz ``$('#txt_cnpj').trigger('change');``depois que fazer ``$('#txt_cnpj').val(_obj_assessoria.cnpj);``.  Ve se isto não faz sua mascara aparecer

Comment: Porque trigger ?

Comment: Acredito que vc so que mostrar as mascara depois que o ajax retorna a sua informação. Usando trigger (tradução: disparador) com a opção 'change' faz que o objeto agir como alguém mudou seu valor. Acho que isso possa também fazer demostrar sua mascara

Comment: Não, a mascara está OK; o que quero é retirar a mascara na requisição ajax

Comment: Entendi meu português nao e o melhor

Comment: voce ja escreveu a função remove_mascara(); Que funções ou libraries esta usando pra aplicar as mascaras.

Comment: https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin

Comment: To vendo que tem a função ``jMask.remove = function() {
            var caret = p.getCaret();
            p.destroyEvents();
            p.val(jMask.getCleanVal());
            p.setCaret(caret);
            return el;
        };``. Ja tentou usar.

Comment: Não sei como faria, pode exemplificar ?

Comment: @WagnerFilho Como você está enviando os dados lá no PHP? Você está utilizando a função `json_encode()`?

Comment: @GodfreytheKing, sim.
Meu problema não é enviar os dados para o servidor.
Até então, eu envio os dados serializados para o servidor.

Porem eu gostaria de criar um objeto antes de enviar, e ao invés de usar o `data: $('#form').serialize()` eu queria enviar como `data: { 'objeto': JSON.stringify(objeto) },`; mas para isto eu teria que criar o objeto antes.
Assim, eu conseguiria tratar os campos individualmente.

Comment: @WagnerFilho, de acordo com o seu código você não está enviando dados para o PHP, e sim buscando-os - método GET.

Comment: @WagnerFilho De acordo com o seu feedback, irei ajeitando a minha resposta.

Comment: @WagnerFilho Acabo de ver, você está se referindo a função `salvar_assessoria()`?

Comment: Exatamente, estou me refererindo ao método post.

Comment: @WagnerFilho Verifique minha resposta.

Comment: @GodfreytheKing, amigo, acho que não entendeu.

Eu fazer a requisição desta forma, o que não estou conseguindo, é criar um objeto para manipular os campos individualmente.
Exemplo:

`objeto.elemento.valor_do_elemento` ou `objeto.cpf = $('#txt_cpf').val();`

Comment: tudo que eu quero, é tratar cada campo manualmente antes de fazer a requisição ajax.
Porque para o campo CPF, por exemplo, estou usando um plugin de mask, e todos os pontos e tracinho está indo para o servidor, daí eu tenho que fazer um str_replace no servidor.
Então eu queria fazer isto, antes de enviar por ajax.
Entendeu ?

Comment: @WagnerFilho Você chegou ver a minha resposta? `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($('#form').serializeArray()))` faz exatamente o que você quer, cria um Objeto com os campos do seu formulário pra você tratar individualmente.

Answer (score 1):

Para você transformar o seu formulário inteiro no formato Objeto JSON, faça:

```
var formulario = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($('#form').serializeArray()))
```

Agora você pode acessar cada item desse objeto e tratar da forma que você quiser.

> Onde `JSON.parse()` converte uma string para JSON.
>
> Onde `JSON.stringify()` converte valores em javascript para uma string
>   JSON.
>
> Onde `serializeArray()` cria um array de objetos.

Se ainda tiver dúvidas, [acesse esse jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avdspf56/3/) e abra o console do seu navegador (no Chrome é o F12) e veja a solução funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

Se voce quer remover os mask antes de enviar os resultados via ajax, o library github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin ten disponível a função `unmask()`. Então a sua função `remove_mascara();` dever ser algo assim

```
function remove_mascara(){
    $('#txt_cnpj').unmask();
    $('#txt_cep').unmask();
    ......

    //Talvez para que o objeto atualiza voce precisa fazer isto.
    //Tenta fazer sem primeiro
    $('#txt_cnpj').trigger('change');
    ....
}
```

Nunca usei esta biblioteca então, mais do que to vendo acredito que isto deve funcionar.

Comment: Sua resposta não condiz com a pergunta.